# How to parse <img src="value" from this XML by using DOM?

Tags: android, xml, domparser

It look like this in XML. I want to get he Image src value...

```
<description><![CDATA[<div class="images"><img src="http://www.voicetv.co.th/cache/images/8a1a6f2aeb7b0e9c1d6bb3eae314165f.jpg" /></div>]]></description>
```

What I am doing is

```
if ((theElement.getElementsByTagName("description")).getLength() > 0) {

            allChildern = theElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getChildNodes();

            for (int index = 0; index < allChildern.getLength(); index++) {
                description += allChildern.item(index).getNodeValue();

                NodeList chNodes = allChildern.item(index).getChildNodes();
                for (int i = 0; i < chNodes.getLength(); i++) {

                    String name = chNodes.item(i).getNodeName();
                    if(name.equals("div")) {
                        String clas = allChildern.item(index).getAttributes().getNamedItem("class").getNodeValue();
                        if(clas.equals("images")){
                            String nName = allChildern.item(index).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName();
                            if(nName.equals("img")) {
                                String nValue = allChildern.item(index).getChildNodes().item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            currentStory.setDescription(description);
        }
```

But is is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description element contains a CDATA node. This means that the `<img>` "element" you are trying to access is really just a piece of text (and not an element at all).

You'll need to parse the text as a new XML document in order to access it via DOM methods.

Comment: I just get description node value. The put the in <data> </data> tag. As DOM allow 1 root element. Here it look like

DocumentBuilderFactory fectory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder builder = fectory.newDocumentBuilder();InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(("<data>"+currentStory.getDescription()+"</data>").getBytes("UTF-8"));
Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);   
String imageURL = document.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue();
   
currentStory.setImagePath(imageURL);

Answer (score 0):

*Warning*: This might be a bit dirty, and it can also be fragile if the xml can contain comments that contains something that looks like image tags.

An alternative to using xml parsing for that short xml snippet that has a cdata section is to get the image url using regexp. Here's an example:

```
String xml = "<description><![CDATA[<div class=\"images\"><img src=\"http://www.voicetv.co.th/cache/images/8a1a6f2aeb7b0e9c1d6bb3eae314165f.jpg\"/></div>]]></description>";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<img src=\"([^\"]+)").matcher(xml);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("img url: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's can be a option. Let me check.